# Find variable name in list and match to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
myList = [2, '+', 3, 'pi']
```

I also have a variable `pi`, which is equal to `3.14`. I want to take the string `'pi'` in `myList`, and match it to the variable `pi`, so when I execute a code to compile the list, instead of outputting `pi`, I want it to output `3.14`, or whatever value the variable `pi` is. Sorry if it's confusing. Is there any method to do this?

I have tried changing `'pi'` to `pi`, but this just gives an error, as `pi` is not an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
import math

CONSTANTS = {'pi': math.pi}
myList = [2, '+', 3, 'pi']

for e in myList:
    print(CONSTANTS.get(e, e))
```

We are creating a dictionary `CONSTANTS` in which you are using the name of the number `pi` as key to retrieve its value which is `math.PI`. Then you iterate over `myList`, and you are saying, if there is a value associated with the key `e` in this case each element in the list, then give me the `value` associated with that key and print it. Otherwise, just print that value.

To convert the list from `[2, '+', 3, 'pi']` to `[2, '+', 3, 3.1415...]`, do the following:

```py
CONSTANTS = {'pi': math.pi}
newList = [CONSTANTS.get(e, e) for e in myList]
```

Comment: I think using `CONSTANTS.get(e, e)` is a little more elegant

Comment: @MZ, you are totally right, it is more elegant and simpler! Updated. Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't quite get it, as it is printing 
`2 + 3 3.141592653589793`

Comment: @fasterthanlight, sure let me add some explanation for you.

Comment: Also, is it possible so that a new list is defined as `[2, '+', 3, 3.14...]`?

Comment: @fasterthanlight, I updated my answer, and I am not sure what you are trying to ask with your previous quesiton.

Comment: So, I do not want the list to be printed, I am wondering if we could redefine `myList` to `[2, '+', 3, 3.14...]`.

Comment: @fasterthanlight, yeah, that is possible, you can convert it, let me add an update.

Comment: @fasterthanlight, answer was updated! It is using a list comprehension

Comment: Does `math.PI` really exist in your Python?

Answer (score 1):

## List Comprehension with a Ternary Operator

```
import math

myList = [2, '+', 3, 'pi']
myList = [x if x != 'pi' else math.pi for x in myList]

print(myList)
```

## Explanation

In python, lists can be created using other lists, this is known as list comprehension.

```
[f(x) for x in list]

f(x) - some function of x
for x in list - passing over each element in the list

Wrapped in square brackets to represent a new list being created.
```

Additionally, python has a somewhat silly looking ternary 'operator':

```
example = x if x != 'pi' else math.pi
```

This is an expression (in python this means it needs to be evaluated and has a
value), example will be equal to x if x is not 'pi', else it will equal math.pi. It is equivalent to:

```
if x != 'pi':
    example = x
else:
    example = math.pi
```

Comment: Can you explain this further?